# Why is .2 not a valid number for jquery.validate.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, razor

This is using jQuery's Validate.

I have a textbox that if you enter a 0.2 validates, but on .2 it fails validation saying it has to be a number.

It fails on the `@Html.ValidationSummary` at the bottom of my razor view.

Problem is .2 is not a number. Anyway to make it a number before it hits validation?

Comment: This is by design. `.2` is in fact not a valid number.

Comment: then how could i make it a valid number without making it invalid for the user toinput that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/gYd6E/)***

You could always implement a small observer to fix the case where a number input starts with `.` like this:

```
$('body').on('blur','input[data-val-number]',function(){
 if( this.value[0] == "." ){
  this.value = "0" + this.value;
  $(this).valid();
 }
});
```

Comment: I need it to be able to accept the .2 because it is being used as a money value of 20 cents

Comment: @user2359134 - It will convert `.2` to `0.2` which is still 20 cents. However, I see that there needs to be one more step which is to ensure that the validation process sees the change. Please see my edit.